# Is there a Rubocop cop for question mark method with ternary operator?

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator, ternary, rubocop

I regard it to be really confusing to use predicate methods (by convention ending with a question mark) in combination with ternary operator.

In my opinion, using thet ternary operator here is bad formatting due to the double question marks it leads to:

```rb
# Returns `true` or `false`
def predicate?
 # ...
end

boolean? ? <truthy branch> : <falsy branch>
```

While these are both good because the aforementioned artefact is avoided:

```rb
# `predicate?` is the same method as listed above
if predicate?
  <truthy branch>
else
  <falsy branch>
end
```

and

```rb
# `predicate` here is a local variable 
predicate ? <truthy branch> : <falsy branch>
```

I would love for my linter to detect this. Is there a ready-made Rubocop cop for this? If not, how would you implement it?

I’ve searched and not found a cop for it.

Comment: You can [write a custom cop](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rubocop-custom-cops-for-custom-needs). You can use [TernaryParentheses](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/ternary_parentheses.rb) as an example cop to build your custom cop. If you're interested in contrary opinions then mine is that there is nothing wrong with `boolean? ? "true" : "false"` and having a cop complain about that but not ternary statements in general would be confusing and frustrating.

Comment: There is a much bigger problem with your code than the conditional operator, though. I would be more concerned about that.

Comment: Interesting, what’s that? @JörgWMittag

Comment: Have you considered `boolean.to_s` ? :)

Comment: LOL. My bad for assuming people would not interpret me literally. `"true"` and `"false"` in my examples are just arbitrary placeholders, of course I would not write the code like that if I literally wanted `"true"` or `"false`". Will update my post to avoid misunderstandings :)